# to come second best, but not in racing

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-request

Would it be natural in English to use "You came second best" applying it to a situation not related to physical running? For example, you are holding a list of one class' students' test's results and see that Jack got 97 points out of 100 points possible, only one student, Glamy, got all 100 points, and all other students fell below 80 points. So you turn to Jack and tell him:

"Jack, you came second best this time!"

Would it sound natural in English?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "best" is optional:

> Jack, you came second this time.

But there is no implication of physical order in "come second", and can apply to any ranking.